# OrientDB query to get sum total from edge property

Tags: sql, orientdb3.0

I'm new to OrientDB and I need some help in writing a query.

I have following classes in my DB:

1. Order {orderId:String, ...}
2. MenuItem {dishName: String, ...}
3. There's an edge 'has_menu_item' from Order -> has_menu_item -> MenuItem.
4. Edge 'has_menu_item' has a property 'orderQty'

The help I need is to write a query where the orderQty needs to be aggregated for each day based on some date condition from Order.orderDate

**Expected Output:**

```
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
|# |Date       |dishName         |Sum(orderQty)             |
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
|0 |12-05-2020 |Pizza            |9                         |
|1 |12-05-2020 |Burger           |5                         |
|2 |13-05-2020 |Burrito          |20                        |
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
```

**My query:**

```
select orderDate, out('has_menu_item').dishName, out_has_menu_item.orderQty 
    from (SELECT EXPAND(IN('has_menu_item')) FROM MenuItem)
```

**Actual output**

```
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
|# |Date       |dishName         |Sum(orderQty)             |
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
|0 |12-05-2020 |[Pizza, Burger]  |[5,5]                     |
|1 |12-05-2020 |[Pizza, Burrito] |[4,12]                    |
|2 |13-05-2020 |[Burrito]        |[8]                       |
+--------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
```

Somehow I'm unable to get desired output. What's the best way to get the result I'm looking for? Thanks in advance.